# Linkedin Api The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: asp.net

I am working on the Linkedin Api. 
In my OAuthLinkedin.cs, 
I have the following:

```
        public string WebResponseGet(HttpWebRequest webRequest)
        {
            StreamReader responseReader = null;
            string responseData = "";

            try
            {
                responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
                responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream().Close();
                responseReader.Close();
                responseReader = null;
            }

            return responseData
```

;
        }
My code is able to get a oauthToken, oauthTokenSecret

WebResponseGet(HttpWebRequest webRequest) is where it fails.
Status:  System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.Protocol error    The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

It is able to get a token secret after requesting permission to access linkedin. 
but I am not sure abt this unauthorized error. is it some permission issue. 
where do I check this

Thanks
Sun

Comment: hopefully you anonymized your token secrets in this post ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of things that you can try to identify the source of your problem:

- Use this OAuth test console and compare the header that you're generating to the one that this tool generates:
  https://developer.linkedin.com/oauth-test-console
  If your header is wrong, then LinkedIn will return a 401 status
- If you're posting XML to LinkedIn in your request, then make sure the content type (webRequest.ContentType) is "application/xml" and not "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", otherwise, LinkedIn will return a 401 status.

Answer (score 0):

It was happening with me too but i figured it out what i was doing it wrong.

Whenever you create Signature, make Token and TokenSecret empty. it worked for me because it was getting old token and token secret from browser request.

```
 //Generate Signature
        string sig = this.GenerateSignature(uri,
            this.ConsumerKey,
            this.ConsumerSecret,
            this.Token,
            this.TokenSecret,
            method.ToString(),
            timeStamp,
            nonce,
            out outUrl,
            out querystring);
```